# Is there currently any way to completely replace cable television with (legal) online resources?

Tags: webapp-rec

I guess all the press with GoogleTV got me to thinking more about this and how I would do it myself.

I'm interested in completely eliminating my cable bill and replacing it with a good net connection and online services. Of course there are sites like Hulu and any of the networks that provide free content after it has aired.

My intention would be to follow the media center design outlined in [this article](http://www.extremetech.com/article2/0,2845,2367455,00.asp), utilizing Mythbuntu and MythTV along with an HD tuner for local stations.

But then what about the other cable stations that don't provide airwaves or online content?

Are there are any sites that would provide the same live TV shows I'm getting through cable?

I'd even be willing to pay a good premium for this service because cable bills are getting so outrageous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing to do is ask yourself: Which stations do I actually need? Because NO ONE watches all the stuff that their cable gives them - that's a large number of channels, many of which appeal to a niche audience, and you are unlikely to actually need (or want) them all.

Once you have a list of things you want to watch, figure out how many are on that HD tuner, and how many aren't. Then you can start to look at Hulu and similar solutions (am I right that Netflix has some current content?) to see how much you'll actually be able to get legally.

You'll never get everything, but perhaps you can get enough to be happy with it.